# Write a file in Python 2.7 without getting blocked by Windows?

Tags: python, windows-7, permissions

I'm writing a simple fuzzer for use on Windows applications based on the Charlie Miller code from the babysitting an army of monkeys talk. However I keep receiving the error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python27/fuzzer.py", line 29, in <module>
    process=subprocess.Popen([app_choice,fuzz_output])
  File "D:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
   startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

Does anyone know how to bypass this? I'm really stumped because I'm not all too familiar with Windows 7 permissions or Python 2.7 to be honest. Full code below

```
#List of file names (all located in the python folder)
fuzz_files=[ "slides_algo-guiding.pdf", "slides_algo-intro-annotated-   final.pdf","slides_algo-merge1.pdf"]
apps=["C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader"
  ]
#Creates an output file in the Python folder
fuzz_output="fuzz.pdf"
FuzzFactor=50
num_tests=1000
import math
import string
import random
import subprocess
import time

for i in range(num_tests):
    file_choice=random.choice(fuzz_files)
    app_choice=random.choice(apps)
    buf=bytearray(open(file_choice,'rb').read())
    #Charlie Miller code

    numwrites=random.randrange(math.ceil((float(len(buf))/FuzzFactor)))+1
    for j in range(numwrites):
        rbyte=random.randrange(256)
        rn=random.randrange(len(buf))
        buf[rn]="%c"%(rbyte)
     #End Charlie miller code

     #Write code
     open(fuzz_output,'wb').write(buf)
     process=subprocess.Popen([app_choice,fuzz_output])

     time.sleep(1)
     crashed=process.poll()
    if not crashed:
       process.terminate()
```

Comment: I have a feeling you will need to run it as an admin to access program files.

Comment: What directory is your current directory when you run this? Keep in mind, writing to a directory under Program Files is somewhat similar to trying to write to /usr/bin or similar system directory on a UNIX machine.

Comment: You file names are not valid, and you need the full path to the executable, not just the directory in order to launch a process.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader` is the path of a *folder*, not an executable. Therefore trying to run it with `Popen` makes no sense.

Also, you should be using raw strings when writing Windows paths `r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 9.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"` or using slashes instead `"C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Reader 9.0/Reader/AcroRd32.exe"`. You were just lucky that there weren't any valid escape sequences in the paths.